# How I can short my token to 40 characters of hash sha512?

Tags: php

To make is it simple I just want to echo the first 40 characters of **sha512**

```
$salt = "fRY^YXCH%^ER^*&^";
$profiletoken = hash("sha512", $salt . $user . $id . $value);
echo $profiletoken;
```

so this will give something like this **output**

```
09821f0ae9bdee372b344b0921582f2e7a3a0587a3b55bb247f200381e92ffd41480e8619b3d575214a7a25c3a9d0f618c6733bed6830ee7b66136b85f8d7568
```

But I just want the first 40 characters

```
09821f0ae9bdee372b344b0921582f2e7a3a0587
```

Thanks and hope I made my self clear

Comment: One question: why ? This defeats the whole purpose, you might just use `sha1()` which will provide you a *valid* hash of length 40.

Comment: **sha512** is my fav and more secure i feel when i use it :)

Comment: Indeed, but when you truncate it to 40 then you just massacred it.

Comment: Whoever upvoted this question, care to explain?

Comment: I'm not a cryptographer, but to be more explicit about the concerns others are expressing: when you truncate the hash you're obviously creating a lot of potential cases where different messages which at full length would've produced different hashes will now produce identical hashes. In _theory_ 40 characters in either case can support a fixed amount of variety without repeating hashes, but since `sha512()` is designed to produce valid hashes of a given length, it doesn't necessarily follow that any given 40-character subset of that hash is as secure as `sha1()`--it may be far worse.

Comment: @abathur: Doesn’t it have to follow that it’s just as secure, though? That would seem to be a pretty serious flaw in the algorithm otherwise.

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3156/7264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$profiletoken = hash("sha512", $salt . $user . $id . $value);
$shortToken = substr($profiletoken, 0, 40);
```

But my question to you would be why are you shortening it to 40 characters? That kind of defeats the point of using SHA512, which produces 128 characters. For SHA512 you can store it in the database as CHAR(128).

```
$profiletoken = hash("sha1", $salt . $user . $id . $value);
echo $profiletoken; // 40 characters long
```

---

**Edit 1:** Don't use SHA1, it's not secure.

**Edit 2:** For anyone who wants to read more about the topic of truncating a hash, I asked about it over on the Cryptography Exchange, and it has since become a very popular question:

[Is truncating a SHA512 hash to the first 160 bits as secure as using SHA1?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9435/is-truncating-a-sha512-hash-to-the-first-160-bits-as-secure-as-using-sha1)

Comment: Its just to identify a profile of user before making any action and it will change as soon value changes its a game i working on so all profile need token as identy :)

Comment: And i am not saving it to database its just temp token

Comment: @deerox I won't be surprised if you find 2 same tokens. Note that sha512 is **not designed** to be truncated. Use this at your own risk.

Comment: why not sha1 directly then, @deerox

Comment: well there is reason for not using other thing like md5 or sha1 etc

Comment: @deerox You said in comment to your original post "sha512 is my fav and more secure i feel when i use it" but that makes no sense. You are taking away the security by cutting it down to 40 characters.

Comment: Assuming the hashes are perfect, truncating one to 40 characters and creating another with 40 characters should be equivalent, no?

Comment: its just temporary tokens and it will change on every click i am not saving it database. cutting to 40 is because no one can identyfy what hash i am using

Comment: @BadHorsie: I don’t mean “they’ll have the same value”, I mean they’ll still be equal in terms of security.

Comment: No, I don't think they will because the SHA1 string is always unique, whereas there may be many SHA512 strings where the first 40 characters are the same (even if the rest of the string is different). I might be wrong as I don't actually know the intricacies of how the hashing works but that is my understanding of it.

Comment: The SHA1 string isn’t always unique. You can’t fit an arbitrary amount of data into a fixed number of bytes. Anyways, see [this answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3156/7264) on Crypto.SE.

Answer (score 2):

substr is all you need.

```
echo substr($profiletoken, 0 ,40);
```

if you are simply using this to generate a unique token to track game state you might want to look at using uniqid or if you are saving the state to the filesystem tempnam

Comment: i was thinking **substr** is used for other things but thanks alot it works :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have enough space for the output of sha512, use a smaller hash:

```
sha1($profileToken);
```

Doing `substr()` on the output of sha512 is reducing its effectiveness and you're just wasting CPU cycles in the process.

Comment: There’s a bit of a difference, though, since SHA-1 has been shown to have weaknesses and SHA is designed for substrings to be as secure. (http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3156/7264) Not that it really matters here…

Comment: Interesting, so you're saying that a 160 bit subset of sha512 is stronger than sha1?

Comment: Maybe, but since deerox says it’s to identify the profile, I don’t think any of the SHA-1 potential problems apply or would be something to worry about. If it were, a full SHA-512 would be much better, of course…